# There's no space to construct a runway. Are early planes still useful and promising technology?

Tags: science-based, alternate-worlds, steampunk, aircraft, industrial-age

My setting exists on a huge vertical cliff with no top or bottom, and currently nearing the end of an steampunk-y industrial revolution, putting its tech level somewhere in the range of 1860s to 1910s. Everybody lives on relatively small and thin ledges or spaces carved out of the rock - the largest are up to 1km wide, but also heavily developed with cities, farms, etc, and too valuable to waste on airports.

They use airships to move cargo around (steam-powered hydrogen zeppelin types, with a couple of handwaves to explain abnormal lift capacity), but the technology level also is such that heavier-than-air aircraft should be at the very least discussed as a possibility already.

You can launch one by just pushing it off the cliff or dropping it from an airship I guess, but seemingly there's nowhere for this aircraft to *return to*, since there's no space to build a landing strip long enough to safely land on ("safely" even by the 1900s standards of safety).

**In this environment, will airplanes be practical to use and develop (and threaten to replace airships)?**

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148110/discussion-on-question-by-darth-biomech-theres-no-space-to-construct-a-runway); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you want something that will be more colorful and relevant to your own setting, heavier-than-air vehicles could be thought of as VTOL things: to launch them, you drop them. Only natural, it's how paper darts/planes are doubtless launched. But to land them, why would their first thought be a horizontal airfield?

They live on a cliff. To lose velocity in something moving there are two options: crash into the cliff (not good), or fly vertically up the cliff until they stall.

So, grab dangling winch cable and then fly vertically upwards until velocity is lost. Done right, winch should be able to reel in the loose cable and match speed with you as you slow down, so that the slowing plane stops being a flying thing, and becomes an object dangling on the end of a crane.

Impractical? Maybe. But VERY cliff-punk.

Comment: It rather conjours the mental image of bats clinging to trees, which I imagine a lot of the cliff-world's wildlife would also resemble, so it's a natural assumption that if you're going to build an aircraft, it will behave like the flying creatures of your world. Ducks land on water like it's a runway, and bats will cling to sheer surfaces and crawl around on them when not flying. An airplane that lands effectively on a sheer wall would be very unique to be sure!

Comment: Fun idea... but insanely dangerous.

Comment: The technical term for that is a perch landing. Birds do perch landings such that they stall and reach zero velocity a the point of contact needing no assisting mechanisms. This is the ideal but may not be practical for larger aircraft.

Comment: @Nosajimiki sounds like a reaction to first airplanes

Comment: @JiK Speaking of 1sts.  The first prototypes for aircraft carriers were ships with decks only 1/2 the length of the first active aircraft carriers.  All though they could be successfully landed on by a skilled piolet (some of the time) so many test piolets were killed or injured trying to use them that they never saw active use.   This idea is far more dangerous than those early carrier decks, especially if you don't also have normal runways for less experienced piolets to train on first.  So, no, this could never be adopted and is a big suspension of disbelief issue IMO.

Comment: Also, uphill runways are a possible compromise between runways and perch landings. They would reduce the footprint projected onto the ground while also shortening the runways length. Also work for for takeoff in the other direction. Would need to add something so the airplane doesn't roll backwards for extreme inclines probably 10 degrees. 20 is pretty extreme. Beyond 30 is probably not practical.

Comment: +1 for cliff-punk :)

Answer (score 25):

The first Carrier landing was 1911:

[image: First Carrier Landing]

Now, in terms of space, that looks to be about 20-30 metres. 1911 is 1 year after the upper-limit of your tech level, however, I'm going to say that this was a function more of 'no need', since there were large areas of open field to land in - whereas in your world, this would be a primary requirement and so would have received greater attention for the problem.

In short: Yes, they would be useful. The technology to successfully do this existed in 1911 and so it completely in the realm of what you outlined.

Comment: are these sandbags linked by rope to help the plane slow down?

Answer (score 24):

### Airships were aircraft carriers

Just after your world timeframe aircraft were launched and landed in airships. It is perfectly reasonable to make an airship your airport. And it’s cool!

[[image: Just after your timeframe aircraft were launched and landed in airships]

If your traffic isn’t too heavy you can use an airship as an aircraft terminal. It sails out to launch and catch aircraft.

But you could be right as well, living on a cliff, they may simply skip the airplane altogether. Airship technology eventually carried us fairly fast, and they had huge payload capacity. There are dirigibles today which can literally move a house! Australian company *SkyLifter* plans services that  include moving aid or even portable hospitals to remote areas - like rural regions or disaster zones - that have poor infrastructure.

Comment: Yes! Parasite aircraft in our world faded out of use as light planes were able to sustain the necessary range for operations on their own, but these concepts continued to be developed into the post-war era. Using one as a stationary airfield would be much easier than as a mobile one.

Answer (score 21):

### Absolutely!

Someone will definitely figure out about heavier than air transport, because air transport is important to this setting. There's a huge incentive to improve flight technology.

### Flaps

Landing will take *some* space, but not too much. Birds flare their wings when they land on a branch to bleed off speed. Assuming your setting has birds and trees, someone would see this and steal the idea. Oversized wings (to allow low speed flight) and oversized flaps (to kill the remaining speed) would be used to slow the aircraft down and minimize run-way requirements.

### And/Or "Tailhooks"

A zero-length runway could involve hanging a loop of rope from a ledge, and catching it with a hook, sort of like a carrier landing in our world. If the rope can play out with some resistance, then the pilot can cut the engine, lower the flaps, and fall until the rope reduces the speed to zero.

I don't know that I'd want to be the first test pilot, but if space is at enough of a premium it would occur to someone!

Comment: Airship aircraft carriers have been used in the real world. The US Navy used to field a couple of them, and they did indeed retrieve carried airplanes by use of tailhooks, which would be caught while flying under the carrier, not landing on a deck.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley key point was that the airships also flew. Airships aren’t as slow as people think, the Hindenburg cruised ar 120km/h. The speed difference is a lot lower. That said, “just” a long rail and a death-defying curve downwards just before the wall and then catching all that speed is absolutely a possibility. But… does it beat an airship or elevator?

Comment: @Demigan - the initial Wright Flyer had a ground speed of something like 15km/hour. A good runner could outpace it. So I'm not really worried about coming in too fast. I would expect airplane designs in this world to focus on rate of climb and maneuverability over raw speed - there's no where to go that involves fast, level flight.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley - that's... terrifying. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

It's plausible to some degree. In large air carriers they "catch" fighter planes, which fly with a considerably higher velocity than 1910s airplanes, with a hook, more specifically a [tailhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tailhook). Maybe something like that could work if the plane is small enough.

Another idea is the [ornithopter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornithopter). I don't know much about it but it was an idea that was always in the background as a potential flying technology until the airplane sort of "won". But why not? Maybe your civilization can develop something like that. People experimented with ornithopters in the 1910s for sure. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TXg-qoRN0co) is a modern ornithopter for fun.

If airplanes develop, I think they'll win over the slower airships in your world.

Comment: I think the question is then: what direction are they going in? If you need on average to go horizontal and then somewhat up or down, then an aircraft can be faster (if unsafer). However especially old aircraft had a slow climb ability. The difference is likely low (especially if the airships can vector thrust, just turn their engines down) but the capacity and safety of the airship is way higher.

Comment: Ornithopters usually still require forward velocity to generate lift, depending on their design - I'm not aware of any practical ornithopters that can hover or land with zero velocity. They can sometimes operate at lower airspeeds, but I don't think they meaningfully change the challenges involved.

Answer (score 9):

> Too valuable to waste on airports.

**FRAME CHALLENGE: This makes no sense unless your world also cannot justify land for roads, paths, or rails.**

Air travel's benefit is that it *only* requires the space of a runway, and for that small amount of space you can cover a far greater distance in less time than road or rail. If your world cannot justify space for a few runways, then it also cannot justify space for roads, paths, or rails which collectively consume far more space and allow travel over much less distance at slower speeds for the space consumed. Therefore the reasoning that the land is too valuable to waste on airports to the extent that you would not even build a single runway holds virtually no water, especially if your ledge cities are some distance away from each other. That would justify one runway per city.

A few runways would enable the society with a unique capability, and what you would be giving up is a small amount of land that would be otherwise be used for facilities which already exist elsewhere. Instead of a dozen farms an zero runways, you would have eleven and a half farms and two runways since a farm is far larger than a runway.

The aircraft in your specified time period also did not require very long runways compared to modern aircraft.

Comment: It sounds like OP's cliff world has flatland-to-flatland transport done by blimp.  So the economics comparison isn't planes-versus-roads but rather planes-versus-blimps.

Answer (score 7):

### Powered Gliders

I could easily see aircraft evolving from gliders in this setting, a glider or parachute is a fast fun way to descend the giant cliff. maybe even much cheaper than an airship. Someone straps an engine to one to travel longer distances or just to prove it works. this gives you a nice smooth development for more engine power without needing to start with one powerful enough to get full lift.

I imagine gliders and parachutes get invented a lot earlier with the ever present fall risk, so the development might not even take much longer.

[image]

Comment: (Using a comment as I don't have points to answer) This kind of powered parachute or Regola wing is a great way to go.  The Insitu Scan Eagle is recovered with a hook at a wingtip.  They fly the wing into a vertical taut line, it slides to the hook, spins around and is recovered.  I would also look to the birds -- birds land with a dynamic stall, but they can do point landings -- say on power lines.  Your steampunk aviation tech could be derived from birds (ornithoper anyone) and could alight like a bird.  Look at cliff dwelling birds for more inspiration.

Comment: @RobMcDonald One issue with catching lines is UAVs don't mind being flung about. Passengers and cargo are not as tolerant. It is also a problem in general with much larger aircraft because they are heavier and must cannot fly as slowly as (I assume) the Scan Eagle can.

Comment: @DKNguyen I agree it is all a matter of scale and proportion...  I imagine that something as slow as a powered parachute could catch a line (horizontal or vertical) as a reasonable means of capture -- something much faster, not so much.  Since we don't know how fast and how far these cliff-punk aviators need to go, it is worth considering.

Comment: Gyrocopters....

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have to start out above your landing site to land on it, or end up above it to take off, you can land on an upward slope, and take off on a downward one.

Comment: This. We build tarmacs level for convenience and safety, but that is a requirement from regulatory agencies rather than from physics.

Comment: On top of that (pun intended), landing uphill means gravity helps you shear speed.

Comment: Those safety regulations exist for a reason based in physics.  Landing uphill puts you at a much higher risk of a low altitude stall which will result in a crash landing.  Piolets can generally only land up hill if they have a good nose wind to maintain lift.

Answer (score 6):

### Frame Challenge: Space is not actually a limiting factor

Just build the runway OVER the Hangers.  Many aircraft carries already take advantage of this idea.  In general, both airplanes and airships need about 3 times as much hanger space as is thier top-down profile. The thing is that early airplanes did not need big runways. The first functional aircraft carrier was the HMS Argus which only had a deck space of about 3500m$^2$.  By creating a flat top building where the roof is the runway, and the bottom is the hangers, you could fit a runway and hangers for about 20 WWI style airplanes into a 1/2 acre space. Even using modern farming techniques, 1/2 an acre is barely enough space to feed a single human being; so, sacrificing this little bit of farmland would be a pretty small ask for a fleet of 20 planes.

This means that with just a little bit of creativity, you need exactly as much space for airplanes as you do for airships that are as small as airplanes. So, even if your airships were 1000 times as buoyant as Earth based airships, they'd still be in danger of being replaced (or at least supplemented) due to thier higher air resistance and lower top speeds.

Answer (score 5):

#### Dolven Aetodromes

With all that vertical real estate, your people can easily bore *into* the huge rocky surface. They could create their aerodromes to any length they need and likely any width or height. Spacious hangars could be bored to either side of the runway too!

The relatively low speed & power of old aeroplanes means relatively short runways and the barn storming skills of early airmen would translate very easily to the skill of approaching a stone wall with a relatively small opening to aim for!

[image]

Comment: While this is an ingenious solution, I suspect it would have unwelcome impact on the rest of the world-building - if boring into the rocks is easy, a lot of other facilities will be cave-based rather than occupying the shelves. Still, an interesting alternative to consider!

Comment: It's probably a matter of economics as to how large/deep tunnels go, and population growth would still be limited by available agricultural terraces, so depending on the social structure/economics of the world, it's possible that much of the industrial infrastructure is already inside the cliff and only the richest people would be able to afford homes with windows anyhow.

Comment: On a single cliff with no known top or bottom boring could cause tremors and wipe out whole cities, even without the person mining ever noticing.

Comment: boring sound inevitable, but even cliff space may be scarce.  You can't just dig forever without risking a landslide destroying all of your farmland; so, chances are most of the cliff face will already be shallow dugouts, almost as scarce as the agriculturally valuable flatlands.

Comment: @IMSoP --- I didn't say it would be "easy". However, actual humans have been building cities into rock for quite a while now. Plus, this world specifies that things like steam shovels and pneumatic tools and explosives are all well known technologies.

Comment: @MarkBooth --- There are other possibilities for motivation, which are beyond the scope of the question. But airplanes of that time didn't need huge long runways either. A boring of maybe 350 feet should do it!

Comment: @user3819867 --- *shrugs* Not really my problem! Presumably, if tremors are a real phenomenon, people will have either learned to adapt or, well, died.

Comment: @elemtilas Given that the cliff is where they live the adaptation is likely an agreement that whichever country starts drilling needs to be stopped at all costs, similarly to undersea mining or nuclear explosion bans on Earth nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

#### Do you have lakes or seas? Then you don't need runways

Today we think of runways as a basic requirement for planes. It wasn't always that way.

Smooth concrete runways cost a *lot* to build, and even more to maintain because concrete degrades badly with weather. Aircraft design in the 1920s had advanced far faster than the financial willpower to build runways, and you couldn't achieve the necessary takeoff and landing speeds on a bumpy grass runway. As a result, *all* high-performance planes were seaplanes. The [trophy for speed around a course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schneider_Trophy) was a seaplane competition for the simple reason that you couldn't get that performance from a plane with a low enough stall speed to tolerate grass runways. Most major airliners were seaplanes too, partly for the same reason, and partly also because they leveraged the existing port infrastructure and port connections to the rest of the country.

Then WW2 happened. Suddenly national defence in all countries required the construction of vast numbers of concrete runways suitable for high-performance fighters and bombers. Post-war, concrete runways built for bombers formed the starting point for almost every major airport in Europe today, and many around the rest of the world. It's notable that countries without large flat areas of useable land have had problems getting connected to the world airline routes, requiring such extreme measures as reclaiming land from the sea to get long enough runways - a similar problem to the OP's world. And some places such as Canada still make extensive use of floatplanes.

In short (or in [Short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Brothers)), floatplanes are your best answer to a world without runways - because they were the answer our world came up with too.

Comment: Not only countries but also sub-national units lacking large flat areas have had to reclaim land from the sea for runways.  Check out PHNL runway 8R/26L in Honolulu.

Answer (score 3):

### Putting the "Hang" in "Hangar"

Your setting allows for very high power-to-weight ratios in your very lightweight aircraft.
This allows pilots to effectively come to a dead halt hovering vertically in mid-air, which means that the usual means of landing is to hover nose-up under an arrangement of docking-hooks and be attached to one of them. This is achieved essentially using boathooks to manipulate the docking hook onto a loop on the nose of the plane.

Once attached, the ground-crews reel in the aircraft and you're home.
The ground-crews can then add further hooks to the wing-tips and tail of your aircraft, rotate you horizontal and lift you into a boarding and maintenance station.

When it's time to leave, the nose and wing-tip hooks are disconnected, and the aircraft is lowered down below the Hangar facility.
To "take off", you are simply dropped into open space once your propellers are spun up.

Answer (score 2):

If your airships have "abnormal" lift capacity, then I suspect airplanes will not be a thing unless they have even more abnormal lift capacity.

Another factor is the the layout of your civilisation: how much horizontal travel vs vertical travel is there? Airplanes are faster at horizontal travel, but airships much better for vertical travel.

Do you have an abundant energy source? Especially for vertical travel the energy requirements of an airplane will be much, much bigger than for an airship.

Do you have rail infrastructure? To me it seems like horizontal railway lines coupled with vertical airship lifts could be a great transportation system.

Comment: I suspect that airships are primarily used for horizontal or diagonal movement. Docks would take up a fraction of the precious terrace space compared to railway tracks, and could be co-located with steam powered lifts which would do the bulk of the lifting much more efficiently.

Comment: @MarkBooth Steam powered lifts are not more efficient than airships. You just need a tiny buoyancy surplus or deficit and then wait until you arrive at you destination without spending any energy on the movement, while the lifts need excavation and power. On the other hand for horizontal movement, the airship needs steam production to power a propeller which is super inefficient, while a train (especially a slow one) has really high efficiency or you could even slope the tracks slightly to make them move for free and compensate for the height loss with airships for free vertical travel.

Comment: Buoyancy isn't free, an airship typically has a fixed buoyancy, if you load it up with cargo above equilibrium, you have to power your propellers to prevent falling, similarly if you unload it below equilibrium, you have to power your propellers to prevent rising (or remain tethered in place). An airship therefore has a power requirement proportional to the difference between the ideal and current cargo weight. A steam winch only pays an energy cost for the difference between the cargo coming  up and the cargo going down, and as you say, direct gearing is far more efficient than propellers.

Comment: Oh, and potential energy isn't free either. Any power you get from potential energy in one direction has too be replaced when going in the other direction, whether that be the train going back up the track, or pulling the buoyant airship back down to a lower level. Both require power.

Comment: @MarkBooth They said in the question they are cheating with the buoyancy...

Comment: I read that, but I didn't read it to mean throwing out the laws of gravity and thermodynamics in their entirety.

Comment: @MarkBooth Fine, then put two airships on a rope with a pulley at the bottom of the cliff like a reverse elevator and use rainwater collected at the top of the cliff as ballast.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that early planes often made do with fields and the like as take-off and landing surfaces. Admittedly they also periodically "ground looped" due to the imperfections of those surfaces.

Seaplanes are another possible solution that doesn't need runways. They may need to struggle harder to take off, though.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** This question literally asks for a super-heavy dose of a handwavium... There is no way to do it otherwise...

**Long answer:**
... so the answer is also a super-heavy frame challenge.

First, some problems with the setup:

1. Vertical cliff with no top or bottom means super-strong downdraft and updraft air currents. They alone will make Zeppelins unworkable, as they would probably need to have a mechanism to completely deflate in order to descend...
2. Updrafts and downdrafts are also heavily dependent on time of day and intensity of the sunlight, which has multiplying effect on already insane ones from #1
3. Air currents will provide so much energy via windmills that it will make steam power literally superfluous. Steam engines arose from the combined need for more coal to be mined and not enough manpower, with basically unlimited power from windmills this makes no sense.
4. Steam power requires a lot of fuel and water to work. Especially early engines were super-inefficient (like: used more coal for unit of travel that they could pull). They were slow and heavy, but offered a lot of pull power at low rpm. However, only after refinement and other improvements they revolutionized transportation.
5. Steam power requires a lot of displacement, meaning that - for example - steam equivalent of 12 hp ICE engine Wright brothers used would be almost 10 times larger, weighing maybe 40 times more. This makes development of powered air flight impossible, as I don't see a way to build an airframe sturdy enough yet light enough for flight to support it. But then again, maybe air currents from #1 would help... Anyway, low rpm means not enough rpm for propeller to generate enough power to provide lift.
6. What are the sources of coal and water to feed the always hungry steam engine? Both would be extremely scarce in the "infinite cliff" setup without deep mining (regardless if the shafts are vertical or horizontal).
7. Mining in a hard rock is very difficult - mountains are usually from granite, which is super-difficult to mine without dedicated tools. Where does the steel (which means iron and coal and trace elements) come from to achieve that? Is the setting a "survivors of an advanced civilization" type?
8. Last but not least - farmland. Where did it came from? Farming requires about 2 acres per person if vegetarian, and don't kid yourself if you think you can go vegan. If one of the biggest ledges is 1km wide, it needs to be 8 km long to accommodate that big of a farmland for a 1000 people. Yes, you could do a lot with multi-level farming (top: soil to farm, lower level(s) for storage, composting for fertilizer etc), but to some extent only... You have to have enough fertile soil to start.
9. Going back to airplanes - where does the petrol for their petrol ICE engines come from (assuming anyone comes around to invent one, given that they are superfluous to already superfluous to needs steam)? Wright Brothers Flyer had 12 HP engine weighing about 170 pounds, yet for example [13 HP Gaar-Scott machine](https://www.farmcollector.com/steam-engines/gaar-scott-zm0z05marzraw/) weighs about 20000 pounds, maybe third of which is the engine itself... And unlike petrol engines, steam engine gets more efficient the bigger it gets (i.e. [compound steam engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_steam_engine)). So you **have to** have ICE petrol engine for airplanes...

Now for the gains of the setup:

1. Due to updraft and downdraft (and it will be mostly updraft), persons could travel between ledges basically effortlessly: just open an umbrella on the edge of that ledge and swoosh! - up you go. Landing on the other ledge can be tricky, but... I'm sure someone will figure out how much lift one person needs to go up and then how big a parachute (if any) needs to be to land.
2. Same goes for cargo - going up is minor problem of big enough kite, going down just requires rough calculation of shape and ballistic trajectory to make the... "jump"
3. Any airplane development could happen around aerodynamically changing configuration: enough wing surface and plane goes up on updraft, retract most of it and it goes down. Literally no need for any kind of engine, just pure physics. And people not afraid of awesome turbulence everywhere, of course.
4. Updraft would offer enormous power-generation capability, which makes lifts super-easy to power.

Without more details on the world you're building only way for you to go is, as mentioned in the beginning, handwavium.

Answer (score 1):

From a purely aerotechnical standpoint, it's not a problem. Short-space recovery of aircraft can be done in any number of ways. Some aircraft have such a low stall speed that they can take off and land in a matter of feet. In the video below, you can see a plane take off in just 15 feet and land in the space of 10 feet. That is just about the overall length of the plane itself, so the aircraft needs essentially maybe 20 feet of runway. And that's a relatively modern plane that is at least capable of carrying a person. By the time it lands, it's no faster than a walking pace.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hPakbghLe38

It depends somewhat on what kind of performance you want your planes to have, but there is rarely only one solution to a technical problem. We use long, wide open runways because we want fast, heavy planes that are easy, safe, and more comfortable to land, but that doesn't mean that runways are the only way to launch and recover planes.

Launching and recovering heavy, fast planes could be a bigger challenge, but still solvable.

The very first plane, the Wright Flyer, was launched with a catapult. The engine was underpowered- so it could *sustain* flight but the aircraft could not take off by itself. In early attempts they could use the wind to get the Flyer airborne, but wind was not a reliable method. The catapult was a small tower with heavy weights and a pulley and rope system- when released, the weights would pull the Flyer about 50 feet along a rail at which the pilot nosed up the plane and would become airborne. This is a neat approach for your world, because you're trading horizontal space for vertical space by using a right-angle pulley. Modern aircraft carriers use catapults driven by steam and electric motors rather than dropping counterweights.

Landing a fast/heavy plane can be done in different ways. Others have already mentioned tailhook systems used on aircraft carriers. Those systems also have a crash net that can be used in the event the tailhook fails (but nets + propellers or jet engines is a bad time). Entire aircraft have been landed with parachutes. They have been snagged out of the air by moving arms. They have been stopped on short runways by using retrorockets.

Answer (score 0):

### Just buy some land.

There isn't "no place to land", as the scenario is described there are many square kilometers of flat space, the problem is just that they're already occupied. This is just another resource-based challenge of developing powered flight that's no different than obtaining any other resource like metal, fabric, or gasoline - you just have to pay for it. The Wright brothers invested thousands of dollars of their own money obtaining the materials to build their airplane, not to mention the value of their years' worth of work. Potential inventors of the airplane in this world just need to invest some money in *land* in addition to materials and labor. The invention of the airplane already required overcoming a significant financial barrier to entry, buying land is fundamentally no different than buying anything else you need to fly.

The only way this doesn't work is if land is truly a priceless commodity that can't be bought or sold for any price, but that doesn't really make sense on a world of infinite scale where the livable area can indeed be expanded, albeit at some cost. This might slow the development of the airplane as it will result in an additional cost that wouldn't otherwise be present, but at some point, someone will deem buying (or creating) 0.001 square kilometers of flat space worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

[Autogyros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autogyro)!  Also known as gyroplanes, gyrocopters, and perhaps other names.

People figured out the basics of vertical flight long before helicopters were practical, they kept running into control issues if power was applied to the main rotor.  Later on there were improvements in materials and machining to allow for cyclical control of blade pitch and blades that were flexible and yet strong enough to hold up to the forces imposed by such an application.

Autogyros show up in some steampunk fiction because they have that "look" of technology from about 1900 to 1920.  They aren't all that practical if there's a runway for takeoff and landing so they died out pretty quickly.  If there's a cliff to launch off from then getting the forward motion for vertical lift is possible.  When needing to land the need for forward motion is not necessary, the aircraft can come in to land by [autorotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorotation) of the lift propeller.

I have seen unmanned airplanes make a vertical landing by use of an oversized propeller and computers to aid in control of the flaps, elevators, and other control surfaces on the airplane.  My guess is this worked because there was enough air over the control surfaces to allow diversion of some of that airflow to prevent the airplane from spinning like a helicopter that lost it's tail rotor.  Maybe with some practice, an airplane optimized for this maneuver, and a bit of "handwavium", this is possible with a human on an airplane using 1890 to 1910 technology.  Some application of the autorotation might help in this too.

I'll agree with other answers that with things like arresting wires on landing, catapults on takeoff, taking advantage of headwinds/updrafts/etc., skilled piloting, and other techniques used on early aircraft carriers that it would not take too much "handwavium" to make it plausible for airplanes to work in tight places.  If space is too tight for even those options then perhaps an autogyro is what would fit.  Flying up a cliff face and then drop power for the plane to fall onto some kind of hook to catch it might work.  That's taking some risks though, far more than some kind of autorotation on an autogyro.  At least given what I know of aircraft, and that might not be saying much.